# Boost chrono run_timer undefined reference

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile the run_timer_example.cpp example in the boost distribution (1.47.0) and I am getting this using the Intel compiler:

```
$ icc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_chrono run_timer_example.cpp
/tmp/iccUIv4Av.o: In function `main':
run_timer_example.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `boost::chrono::run_timer::run_timer(boost::system::error_code&)'
run_timer_example.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `boost::chrono::run_timer::report(boost::system::error_code&)'
```

and using GNU:

```
$ g++ run_timer_example.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_chrono
/tmp/cc3ZOLLF.o: In function `main':
run_timer_example.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `boost::chrono::run_timer::run_timer(boost::system::error_code&)'
/tmp/cc3ZOLLF.o: In function `boost::chrono::run_timer::~run_timer()':
run_timer_example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6chrono9run_timerD2Ev[_ZN5boost6chrono9run_timerD5Ev]+0x3b): undefined reference to `boost::chrono::run_timer::report(boost::system::error_code&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I gave up in the end.  It appears my install of Ubuntu cannot deal with compiling Boost 1.47.0 correctly and thus I cannot use it.  Shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example was there before the review and uses some interface that is not part of the reviewed Chrono library. I forgot just to remove it. Done in 1.48.

Sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the link order.

```
$ icc run_timer_example.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_chrono
```

I'm not sure how `icc` does it, and I'm not even sure how GCC does it with `-l`, but I vaguely recall that, under some scenarios, linking only brings symbols into the executable if they are used in an object that came before the linked library on the command line.

Comment: I am afraid not.  I have added the output for g++ as well.  I must be missing something really obvious!

Comment: I can't explain the error message if this is the issue, but [the docs say `In addition to link with the Boost.Chrono library you need also to link with the Boost.System library.`](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html). (They also say you can make Chrono header-only...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to `Boost.System` as well.

```
$ icc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_chrono run_timer_example.cpp
```

For more information refer to the [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html#chrono.users_guide.getting_started):

> In addition to link with the Boost.Chrono library you need also to link with the Boost.System library. Once Boost.System will be configurable to be a header only using BOOST_SYSTEM_INLINED you will no need to link with it.

Comment: Hum, that does not work either.  I think that I must have messed up the way boost was installed.